# How to get the non-strike price amount in selenium using xpath?

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

This is the url of the Webpage I am trying to automate:

http://www.qaclickacademy.com/courses-description.php

I want to get the value of the non-strikethrough price (currently $ 20.00) using Selenium and an XPath locator.

A snippet of the HTML markup that includes the element I am interested in is:

```
<div class="course row" data-scroll-reveal=""
     style="-webkit-transform: translatey(24px);transform: translatey(24px);opacity: 0;-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.66s ease-in-out 0s,  opacity 0.66s ease-in-out 0s;transition: transform 0.66s ease-in-out 0s,  opacity 0.66s ease-in-out 0s;-webkit-perspective: 1000;-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;"
     data-scroll-reveal-initialized="true">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a href="course-detail.php?id=130&amp;t=websecurity-testing-for-beginners-qa-knowledge-to-next-level">
            <img src="/courses-description.php?show=130" alt="websecurity-testing-for-beginners-qa-knowledge-to-next-level" class="img-responsive" width="186" height="123">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8">
                <h3>
                    <a href="course-detail.php?id=130&amp;t=websecurity-testing-for-beginners-qa-knowledge-to-next-level">
                        WebSecurity Testing for Beginners-QA knowledge to next level
                    </a>
                </h3>
                <div class="meta">
                    <span><i class="fa fa-user"></i><a href="#">Rahul Shetty</a></span>
                    <span><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>60 Lessons</span>
                    <span><i class="fa fa-folder"></i><a href="#">Penetration testing</a></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 price">
                <del style="font-size:15px;color:#aaa">$ 85.00</del>
                <br>
                $ 20.00
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p class="course-desc">
                    Course Launch Date : Aug 30th 2015 -Its Time to Protect our Websites from Security Attacks This Tutorial will give all the weapons you needed to investigate and
                    unlock the Security Holes in the Web applicationCourse lectures are conceptually driven with root level explanations and bring you to the level where you can
                    bring out the security bugsCourse Contents: Basics of Security Testing...
                    <br>
                    <a href="course-detail.php?id=130&amp;t=websecurity-testing-for-beginners-qa-knowledge-to-next-level">
                        Read More
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried many ways, but so far I have been unable to find a solution

Comment: Try this it will work //del[contains(text(),'$ 85.00')]

Comment: Output should be "$ 20.00". The price is dynamic. It will change on frequently...

Comment: which one, there are 4

Comment: first product price "$20.00"

Comment: Which language binding are you using? Java/Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The non-strikethrough price i.e. the text **$ 20.00** is a *text node* and to retrieve the text you can use the following solution:

- *Java* solution:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='course row']//div[contains(@class, 'price')]")));
  String myText = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;", element).toString();
  System.out.println(myText);
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  $ 20.00
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the method in python that will get only the price ($20.00). 
Note: This will work not both cases where you have stricken price or not.

```
def get_text_exclude_children(element):
    return driver.execute_script(
        """
        var parent = arguments[0];
        var child = parent.firstChild;
        var textValue = "";
        while(child) {
            if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
                    textValue += child.textContent;
                    child = child.nextSibling;
        }
        return textValue;""",
        element).strip()
```

How to use here.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='col-md-3 col-sm-4 price'])[1]")
price = get_text_exclude_children(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xpath=//section[@id='content']/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]
```

Comment: Both value is reflecting $85.00 $20.00. Need to get the nonstrike value

Comment: Can you try adding another [2] at the end?

Comment: Not going to do anything, the OP is trying to find a text node not an element

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know how to answer your question without more detail, there are multiple items on the page that have a strike through / non-strike through amount.

For a generic solution you could use the following, it will match multiple blocks that have prices though.  If you want something a bit more targeted you will need a slightly more complex locator that specifies the item as well as the price block.  If you just want the first price block on the page this will work though:

```
//*[contains(@class,'price')]
```

This is the same as the following CSS selector (which is much less complex)

```
.price
```

However the mark-up is going to cause you a problem, it looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 price">
    <del style="font-size:15px;color:#aaa">$ 85.00</del>
    <br>
    $ 20.00
</div>
```

In strict XPath you could do this use an XPath like:

```
//*[contains(@class,'price')]/text()
```

However Selenium doesn't allow you to bind a text node into a WebElement.  This means that while the above Xpath will work directly in a browser, it will not work as a locator to find a WebElement (because it doesn't find an element, it finds a text node).

The best way to fix it, is to raise a bug and get the dev to place the amount that is not struck through into its own element (e.g. wrap it with a `<span>`).

As a hacky work-around you could try getting the inner HTML of the element like this:

```
WebElement price = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".price"));
String elementHTML = price.getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

The String elementHTML will then contain the following:

```
<del style="font-size:15px;color:#aaa">$ 85.00</del>
<br>
$ 20.00
```

You will then need to parse the String to strip out the first two lines (It's not a nice or reliable solution though).